# on the proof of Theorem 2.11 of Ratliff's "On prime divisors of $I^n$, $n$ large"

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let us consider Ratliff's paper from 1975 entitled [On prime divisors of $I^n$, $n$ large](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1029001769), in particular the last statement of the first paragraph of the proof of Theorem 2.11.

We have a Noetherian semi-local ring $A$ with maximal ideals $M_1,\dots,M_h$ and an ideal $I$ inside the Jacobson radical $\cap_i M_i$. Suppose that every element of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ arises as an associated prime of $I^n$ for some $n \ge 1$. It may be the case that $A/M_i$ is not an infinite field for some $i$. Then Ratliff says that we can get around that by extending to $A(X)$. What does he mean by that? How do we get infinite residue fields, why is the ring still semi-local and why every element of $\operatorname{Spec} A(X)$ is still an associated prime of $I^n(X)$ for some n? By the way, i suppose that by $A(X)$ he really means $A[X]$.

Comment: AFAIK, $A(X)$ denotes the ring of fractions of $A[X]$ with respect to the multiplicative set of polynomials $f\in A[X]$ having the property $c(f)=A$. (Here $c(f)$ stands for the content of $f$, that is, the ideal generated by the coefficients of $f$.)

Comment: @user26857: That's very useful thanks. I can now see that $Q$ is an associated prime of $A/I^n$ if and only if $Q A(X)$ is an associated prime of $A(X) / I^n A(X)$. The only thing that now remains unclear is the following: by construction in Ratliff's proof, every element of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is an associated prime of $A/I^n$ for some $n$. It is not clear that this property carries over to $A(X)$, that is, is every element of $\operatorname{Spec} A(X)$ an associated prime of  $A(X) / I^n A(X)$ for some $n$? I do see though that this is true for the maximal ideals of $A(X)$.